# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: Insert HTML

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to use [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to extract some html from page B and insert the html code into the current page. (Please be gentle, I'm a PHP newbie)

Page B html I'm targeting looks like this:
    `<div id="testdiv">B</div>`

I need the same code to be inserted in current page.

My PHP on current page:

```
<?php
include_once '%resource(simple_html_dom.php)%';
$ret = Array();
$html = file_get_html('b.html');
$ret[] = $html->find('div[id=testdiv]', 0);
$ret->outertext = $ret->makeup() . $ret->innertext . '</div>';
echo $ret;
?>
```

I've tried to cobble this together, but still no luck.  I would expect when viewing the current page to see "B", but I definitely need all the html coding to be there as well ;)
Currently getting an error "Call to a member function makeup() on a non-object"

P.S. Once that's running, I probably need a way to bring in the css and js that's on pg B.

Thanks for the help,  Bill

UPDATED Code:

```
<?php
include_once '%resource(simple_html_dom.php)%';
$html = file_get_html('b.html');
foreach($html->find('div[id=testdiv]') as $ret)
  echo $ret;
?>
```

So now I need to be able to get specif css & js files from page B so whatever content is in the div will render properly.  Here's an example [Current Page](http://www.partiproductions.com/copyr/index.php) If you look in the header of Page B there will be a typical css and js file called b_files/stacks_page_page1.css & b_files/stacks_page_page1.js

These are the files I need to have referenced in the current page w/ the relative path changed as necessary.  I also added a Page C which is in a folder (B is in root w/ current page) so path will be differnt.  I guess combining the css files together & js files together would be good so there aren't a bunch of dom calls.

Overall, what's the code to bring those files in?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the "Call to a member function makeup() on a non-object" because $ret is an array and doesnt have a method called "makeup()."

I am not sure exactly all you are trying to do but something like this might get you a little closer. I am assuming you have some function named makeup() that produces a string "< div>":

*Not Tested*

```
<?
php include_once '%resource(simple_html_dom.php)%';  
$html = file_get_html('b.html'); 
$ret = $html->find('div[id=testdiv]', 0)->innertext; 
$ret = makeup() . $ret . '</div>'; 

echo $ret; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Colin, I saw makeup on another post - thought it was a standard PHP function - I'm going to eliminate that.  See Updated code above and final question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with the code.   `$ret[]` means push onto the array, but then the next line you are calling object methods, which is why you get the error.

Once that problem is fixed, `$ret->makeup` is not a valid method according to the API (unless you have modified/extended it).  I'm not sure what you think you're doing with `$ret->outertext = $ret->makeup() . $ret->innertext . '</div>'`, but if you're expecting `B` in your output:

```
<?php
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('b.html');
$ret = $html->find('div[id=testdiv]', 0);
if ($ret) {
    echo $ret->innertext;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I eliminated outer/inner stuff.  See Updated Code & final question.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($html->find('div[id=testdiv]') as $content)
    echo $content;
```

the result woud be `<div id="testdiv">B</div>`
and it will be displayed on the browser as

```
B
```

if you want to display the code:

```
foreach($html->find('div[id=testdiv]') as $content)
    echo "<xmp>".$content."</xmp>";
```

real result: `<xmp><div id="testdiv">B</div></xmp>`

then on the browser's display:

```
<div id="testdiv">B</div>
```

Comment: Thanks user, using the foreach  works.  See Updated Code above and final css/js question.

Comment: no problem! please vote up my answer IF it really helped you. :-) obviously, i'm trying to gain more reputation. :-)

Comment: I did vote up your answer :)  Still need that final question answered. Thanks, Bill

Comment: I've read your css/js question. What do you mean, you want to get the "css"? Can you cite up one example please

Comment: Ok, updated the question and gave complete explanation and example.  Let me know if you need more info. Bill

Comment: I suggest, on your b.html file, you'll just put "style" tag. `<div id="testdiv" style="margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px;">B</div>` , so that everytime you foreach, the style is there. but if it has too many style, I suggest that you should have load the .css in a.html too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17900/discussion-between-parti-and-user1732887)